# MS Access: how to increase the width of form

Tags: forms, ms-access, width

In my ms access project, the width of the form is 55cm. I tried to change it to 100cm but it automatically change to 55cm again. But for my form I really need the width around 100cm. Is there any way to increase the width of the form?

Comment: if you add elements to the form that are around 100cm wide the form will try to display them entirely and therefore will be this wide as well. An Label with no content for example would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

An Access Form can only be 22 Inches (55.87 cm) you cannot have bigger than this. This is a restriction by design.